# How to use jquery appendTo another div .... and back again

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, append

When an item is clicked inside div1, it is appended to the inside of div2. (This works really well!) However I then click the item inside div2 (hoping it will return to div1) but nothing happens. Any ideas very welcome. Is the dom not being updated? Is my selector correct?

```
<div id="div1">
<div class="items">Audi</div>
<div class="items">Jeep</div>
<div class="items">Mini</div>
</div>

<div id="div2"></div>

$('#div1 .items').click(function(){
    $(this).appendTo("#div2");
});


$('#div2 .items').click(function(){
    $(this).appendTo("#div1");
});
```

Comment: Please give us your full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
 $(function(){
   $("#div1").on("click", ".items", function(){
     $("#div2").append($(this));
   });
  });
  
  $(function(){
   $("#div2").on("click", ".items", function(){
     $("#div1").append($(this));
   });
  });
});
```

```css
div{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1">
  <h2>Div 1</h2>
  <div class="items">Audi</div>
  <div class="items">Jeep</div>
  <div class="items">Mini</div>
</div>

<div id="div2">
  <h2>Div 2</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks. The appendTo is working fine.
However your suggestion of using on("click").. fixed my code. My divs and items were dynamically created and this handles them.